# Deploy Resharper 9.2 Plugin as a dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper-9.0, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

For Resharper 7.1 we had written a Resharper Plugin - which was placed in the `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\Plugins`
folder. In VS 2012 the plugin worked without any issue.

The intention of the plugin is to analyze the currently open C# file and check whether our companys file header is written on top of the page. If not it will highlight the entire content.

Now we switched over to Resharper 9.2. I successfully compiled the source code against the Resharper 9.2 SDK downloaded by nuget. But I don't get the Resharper Plugin recognized/working by Resharper.

Did there anything change where the plugin should be placed? I read some suggestions about creating a nuget package - but is this step really neccessary?

I would like to learn how to get the Plugin running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad mood to not read the documentation before asking a question. The R# documentation is quiet helpful.

How I solved the problem:

I renamed the project such that a '.' is in the project and assembly name, lets say `Company.MyPlugin`. I'm completly new in nuget, but I figured out that I need to run `>nuget.exe spec` in the directory where the `Company.MyPlugin.csproj` is located. Nuget will create a `Company.MyPlugin.nuspec` file which I had to edit. I removed some parts since I do not want to deploy the plugin online.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Company.MyPlugin</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>My Plugin Title</title>
    <authors>Myself</authors>
    <owners>Company</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Some description.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2015</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Wave" version="[3.0]" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\Company.MyPlugin.dll" target="DotFiles" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Note that I want to make the package available for R# 9.2, so I need a dependency to Wave 3.0. Somewhere I read that there should also be a dependency to Resharper 9.2 and somewhere it was stated out that this is no more neccessary. It worked for me without the Resharper 9.2 dependency.

Create the nuget package with `>nuget.exe pack Company.MyPlugin.nuspec`. Some warnings will appear concerning that the assemblies are not in the `lib` folder. Ignore these warnings.

It was not yet done. Since JetBrains moved from the product R# to the Resharper Platform I had to create a so called `ZoneMarker`. These days JetBrains says that there is not yet appropriate tooling to figure out what the proper ZoneMarker is (see [JetBrains Devguide HowTo ZoneMarker](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Platform/Zones/HowTo.html)). As a temporary solution you can define an empty ZoneMarker.

```cs
using JetBrains.Application.BuildScript.Application.Zones;

namespace Company.MyPlugin
{
  [ZoneMarker]
  public class ZoneMarker
  {
  }
}
```

Having the ZoneMarker added I was able to compile the assembly, run `nuget` to create a packe. Adding the proper directory to the Package Sources in R# options menu let MyPlugin successfully appear in the Extensions Manager and - that's pretty cool - it was working. :)

I strongly recommend to read the devguide. Have a look at the [JetBrains Devguide Extensions Troubleshooting](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Troubleshooting.html) also.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with R# 9 simple xcopy-deployment doesn't work anymore and you need to create a NuGet package (also if you don't plan to publish your extension).

See [Initial Installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Plugins/ProjectSetup/InitialInstallation.html) and [Local Installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Deployment/LocalInstallation.html) in the R# DevGuide.